# How to keep only duplicates on a STL vector<string>?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Given an STL vector, output only duplicates:

```
INPUT {"A","A","B","B","C","D","E","F"};
OUTPUT {"A","B"}
```

I'm really a novice in stl so don't know where to start. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Iterate through the vector. Add new items to a std::set. Before adding to the set test If a string is already in the set and if so put it in the output vector.

Comment: Beware Daniel, your input is not even correct. `"A` instead of `"A"`!!

Comment: How can I check if the string is already in the set? Iterate through the set looking for it?

Comment: Is the range of strings sorted?

Comment: Use the `find` method of `std::set`

Comment: "How can I check if the string is already in the set?" - Why do you care? A set does not store duplicates, so adding one is harmless.

Comment: What do you do with `{"A","A","A"}`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl oh, I got it now, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

One obvious way would be to walk through the inputs, and count them in a map. Then walk through the map and output each string for which the count is greater than one.

```
map<string, int> counts;

for (auto const &s : input)
    ++counts[s];

for (auto const &s : counts)
    if (s.second > 1)
        outputs.push_back(s.first);
```

Another possibility (especially useful if you need to maintain the original order) is to insert the strings into a set (or unordered_set) as you walk through the input. Then if that fails, the string is already in the set so you write it to the output.

If (as I'd guess to be the case) you only want each duplicated item to appear once in the output, you'll probably want to change that to a map of Booleans. When you initially insert an item, the Boolean will be set to false. The second time you see that item, you'll check the Boolean. When it's false, write out the item, and set it to true. If it's true, that means it's already been written, so don't write it out again.